# How to turn a Dataframe into an Array with certain specifications on Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have have difficult in figuring out how I can turn my specific dataframe from my excel spreadsheet df[50] into a data frame with some specifications. (I do not want the first value into the array). For example df[50] consists of:

print(df[50])

```
    0  50
    1  29.52
    2  29.97
    3  29.52
    4  29.97
    5  31.5
    6  33.93
    7  36.54
    8  34.02
    9  33.48
    10 32.04
    11 33.03
    12 35.01
```

What I would like is:

```
[29.52, 29.97, 29.52, 29.97, 31.5, 33.93, 36.54, 34.02, 33.48, 32.04, 33.03, 35.01]
```

how would i go about skipping the first value?

Thanks.

Comment: `df[50].iloc[1:]` should work?

Comment: when you say array are you meaning a pandas series, numpy array or list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use function `tolist()` from subset  of `df` selected rows by position `iloc[1:]`:

```
print df[50]
#0     29.52
#1     29.97
#2     29.52
#3     29.97
#4     31.50
#5     33.93
#6     36.54
#7     34.02
#8     33.48
#9     32.04
#10    33.03
#11    35.01
```

List of string:

```
print [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in df[50].iloc[1:].tolist() ]
#['29.97', '29.52', '29.97', '31.50', '33.93', '36.54', '34.02', '33.48', '32.04', '33.03', '35.01']
```

List of float:
I has to use function round, because interpretation of float. [More info](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

```
print [ round(elem, 2) for elem in df[50].iloc[1:].tolist() ]
#[29.97, 29.52, 29.97, 31.5, 33.93, 36.54, 34.02, 33.48, 32.04, 33.03, 35.01]
```

Series:

```
print df.iloc[1:,50]
#1     29.97
#2     29.52
#3     29.97
#4     31.50
#5     33.93
#6     36.54
#7     34.02
#8     33.48
#9     32.04
#10    33.03
#11    35.01
#Name: name, dtype: float64
```

Numpy array:

```
print np.array(df[50].iloc[1:].tolist())
#[ 29.97  29.52  29.97  31.5   33.93  36.54  34.02  33.48  32.04  33.03  35.01]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your looking for:

```
df[50].values[1:]
```